# Using Google reverse geocoding in order to find city and province

Tags: android, google-maps

We are currently developing an Android app in which we use google map. We need to get the city and province of a given lon-lat. My question is if calling the reverse geocoding service like
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false" from the app is prohibited or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is not prohibited, but it's rate limited and subject to usage limitations from google's API.

You should probably estimate your usage and check if you will not go over the free quota provided

Comment: if we do not use the API key in the request how they are going to track our usage?

Comment: It's still rate-limited by IP at the least. For instance, sending rapid-fire requests returns an error after the first ten for me, even with no API key.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use the web API, and it doesn't appear to be tracked.  There is also a built in [Android Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html), but it has an issue where it occasionally returns an [IOException](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38009) for no apparent reason.